# Setting D3 js Y axis scale depending on data

Tags: d3.js

I need to scale d3 line chart depending on data minimal value, so that Y axis should   start not from zero.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");







var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);


    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.created_at); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.temp); });

    var line2 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x2(d.created_at); })
        .y(function (d) { return y2(d.temp); });


 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.created_at; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.temp; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());
```

Tried to use floatingScale, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.temp; }))`. Just a curiosity: what is a floatingScale?

Comment: Thanks, seems to work). floatingScale is a d3 library: https://github.com/darshit-shah/d3.floatingScale

Comment: Well, it's not a D3 library, it's a D3 plugin. When using a plugin make it clear in the question (otherwise people will think it's a new D3 method).